# Python Dataframe to import multiple Excel files - stuck with adding the filename to the dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to import all files from a given folder, and one sheet information from all files should go to one dataframe - that is done.

Where I am stuck now is while importing each dataframe from one workbook and before appending to the masterdataframe for that sheet, this dataframe should be concatenated with the filename which has been imported.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = "C:/backup/vp/apr 11 2018 and related files/All Files/"
#print(os.listdir(path))

all_files = [path+file for file in os.listdir(path)]
#print(all_files)

all_files = [file for file in os.listdir(path)]
#print(all_files)

accepted_extensions = ["xlsx"]
xlsx_extension_file1 = [fn for fn in os.listdir(path) if fn.split(".")[-1] in accepted_extensions]
#print(xlsx_extension_file)
xlsx_extension_file = [path+fn for fn in os.listdir(path) if fn.split(".")[-1] in accepted_extensions]
#print(xlsx_extension_file)
df1= pd.DataFrame()
df2= pd.DataFrame()
for file in xlsx_extension_file:
    print(file)
    data = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    #df= pd.DataFrame()
    try:
        df1 = df1.append(data.parse("vInfo",header=0),ignore_index=True)
        #df1frame('FileName')=df1.fill
        #df1 = df1[df1['Host'].str.contains('nl03esx141ccpv1')]
        df2 = df1.append(data.parse("vDatastore",header=0),ignore_index=True)
        #df2 = df2[df2['Name'].str.contains('bb2')]
        #df1['filename'] = os.path.basename(file)
        #df1.append(df1['filename'])
        #df2['filename'] = os.path.basename(file)
        #df2.append(df2['filename'])
        #print(frame.head())
    except:
        pass
#print(df1)
#print(df2)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output1.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer, 'vInfo')
df2.to_excel(writer, 'vDatastore')
#df1.to_html('html14apr2018vInfo.html')
input()
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add column for filename. Also, consider using lists to collect all dataframes and then concatenate together at end instead of expanding same master dataframes within loop:

```
...
df1_list = []
df2_list = []

for file in xlsx_extension_file:
    print(file)
    data = pd.ExcelFile(file)

    try:
        df1_list.append(data.parse("vInfo",header=0).assign(filename=file))
        df2_list.append(data.parse("vDatastore",header=0).assign(filename=file))

    except:
        pass

df1 = pd.concat(df1_list, ignore_index = True)
df2 = pd.concat(df2_list, ignore_index = True)
...
```